# How to create custom views on survey lists

Tags: list, list-view, survey-list

in SharePoint 2007
I want to create custom views on survey lists
without usung sharepoint designer or sharepoint server.

is it possible?

Comment: I believe you can using OOB functionality: https://sharepointmike.wordpress.com/2013/01/19/adding-views-to-a-sharepoint-survey/  This should work on Moss 2007 as well

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can create custom views through browser with out using SharePoint Designer.
Please follow below steps.

Select any Survey list-->Survey Settings

```
http://********/InvIncidentReporting/_layouts/survedit.aspx?List=%7BBF870743%2D9654%2D4E19%2DB4B1%2D35527D4BE942%7D
```

Edit URL with viewtype in place of Survedit

```
http://********/InvIncidentReporting/_layouts/viewtype.aspx?List=%7BBF870743%2D9654%2D4E19%2DB4B1%2D35527D4BE942%7D
```

Now you are able to see all types view and you can create views based filters,sorting, grouping etc like custom/issue tracking list.

Answer (score 1):

you can programmatically render the answer form of the survey as the survey is actually a web part and the columns are questions, so it just need to write a code to iterate all columns "only columns that can be sorted because these columns are the questions columns only"

check this post

http://waelmohamed.wordpress.com/2010/02/16/generate-sharepoint-form-to-save-items-into-sharepoint-lists-dynamically-with-sharepoint-web-controls/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you certainly mean but if you mean you want to do this by code this is as usual possible to do.

A good start is maybe to look over here:

[Programmatically create views](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmyancs/archive/2008/03/15/programmatically-create-a-view-custom-view-of-a-list-and-change-the-view.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a custom view in 2007 without using code. It's just a bit tricky cause you need to understand how to manipulate the SharePoint URL.

Here are two links I find which shows you how to do this:

http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Create-a-Custom-View-for-Survey-List-96.php

http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2008/11/25/creating-custom-views-on-survey-in-sharepoint/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SharePoint Designer.
Open list, select View and edit.
In the ViewField section you can add the internal names of the fields.

```
<ViewFields><FieldRef Name="DisplayResponse"/> ... more fields ... </ViewFields>
```